# Deck transformation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I read that a deck transformation is uniquely defined by the value of one point.

Unfortunately, I don't understand where this comes from. I mean, all we know is that there is one point in the fibre that is mapped to some other element of the same fibre. Why do I know what the other elements in the fibre do and especially why do I know the images of the other elements of the covering space? Could anybody explain where this comes from?

Comment: Assume the base is connected. Pick a small neighborhood around $f(p)$, where $p$ is the point you know the value of. Pull back this small neighborhood to a disjoint union of neighborhoods in the cover. Think about where continuity would force points that are near $p$ to go. If the base is not connected this is false for trivial reasons.

Comment: @MikeMiller maybe I misunderstand, but I think that it is clear that all values in the neighbourhood of $p$ have to go to the same sheet as $f(p).$ But this does not tell me where an arbitrary point goes.

Comment: So now you know that the value is specified on a neighborhood of $p$. The idea is to keep doing this until every value is specified. More precisely: let $a \sim b$ if whenever we specify the value of a deck transformation on $a$, if specifies the value at $b$. Check that this is an equivalence relation. You just proved that equivalence classes are *open*. Now invoke connectedness.

Comment: @MikeMiller so assume that we specified $p$ then the class $[p]$ is open and so the covering space $X\backslash[p]$ is closed. Conversely, $X\backslash[p]$ is also open, because it is a union of equivalence classes. Hence by connectedness, we have $X = [p]$, thanks. :-)